# Cannot Find name Partial

Tags: node.js, angular, express, ngx-bootstrap

I am using `ngx-bootstrap 1.9.2` npm package, but when I try to compile, my project, angular throws following error:

> ERROR in C:/xxx/xx/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.component.d.ts (46,15): Cannot find name 'Partial'.
>
> ERROR in C:/xxx/xx/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-daterangepicker.component.d.ts (45,15): Cannot find name 'Partial'.

As Partial was introduced in ts version 2.1, I tried upgrading typescript version from 2.0.0 to 2.5.2 nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

we use typescript 2.4.2, because it's mandatory for angular@5.
What can help:

- check global version of typescript
- check local version of TS (and clean install and clean build)
- if you are using Visual Studio, it has addition TS version
  (this link may help https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5995 )

Comment: I didn't find any relevant help here

Comment: Whenever ng-build is executed cmd console throws above error

Answer (score 0):

It was just cache issue, I just perform npm cache clean and performed clean install and my problem was solved.

By the way thanks all, for your comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after doing the following steps.

1. install the latest typescript version globally. use below command.
    npm install -g typescript@latest
2. Clean the npm cache using
   npm clean cache
3. Install the latest typescript locally.
   npm install -g typescript@latest

And it worked for me. Hope it helps.